# Prettier foreach - Range extensions cannot operate on enumerators or in async

Tags: c#, .net, range

I tried to replace `foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, _gridCount))` with `foreach (var i in 0.._gridCount)` because it looks prettier and it  has good performance as well.

When I attempted to do so, the `foreach` showed the following error:

> 'foreach' statement cannot operate on enumerators of type 'RangeEnumerator' in 'async' or iterator methods because 'RangeEnumerator' is a 'ref' struct

How do I fix it?

```cs
public IEnumerable<double> GridLevels()
{
    var step = (_upperLimit - _lowerLimit) / _gridCount;

    foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, _gridCount))
    {
        var price = _lowerLimit + step * i;
        yield return price;
    }
}
```

```cs
public static class RangeExtensions
{
    public static RangeEnumerator GetEnumerator(this Range range) => new(range);

    public ref struct RangeEnumerator
    {
        private readonly int _start;
        private readonly int _length;
        private int _count;
        public RangeEnumerator(Range range)
        {
            var (offset, length) = range.GetOffsetAndLength(int.MaxValue);
            (Current, _start, _length, _count) = (offset - 1, offset - 1, length, 0);
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            (var result, _count, Current) = (_count < _length, _count + 1, Current + 1);
            return result;
        }

        public void Reset() => (Current, _count) = (_start, 0);

        public int Current { get; private set; }

        public void Dispose() { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you happen to have followed this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jmmz1cInNow ? Make sure you are on a current version of dotnet and C#, then.

Comment: @Fildor, yes and I'm using .NET 7.0.100 SDK.

Comment: Ah, now I see the difference: Nick is not using it in an iterator _method_. Have you tried to build the enumerable and return it instead of `yield`? If that works, maybe it will give you some hints as to how to make it work with iterator methods?

Comment: Why not remove `ref`?

Comment: @shingo, it worked that way. Hmmm. You can write it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says *"because 'RangeEnumerator' is a 'ref' struct"*, so removing the `ref` keyword should fix it.

```
public struct RangeEnumerator
{
}
```